# Why won't my PHP mail() function send linebreaks?

Tags: php

Here's the script:

```
<?php

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];

    $recipient = "me@christianselig.com";
    $subject = "Message From Website";
    $body = "[From: " . $name . "]\r\n\r\n" . $message;
    $headers = "From: " . $email . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    $success = mail($recipient, $subject, $body, $headers);

    echo $success;

?>
```

On this page: christianselig.com/contact.html

My message will send without any linebreaks. I have it set to separate the [From: xxx] section from the message with a double linebreak, so it should look like this:

> [From: John]
>
> Hey.

But it doesn't.

If I make the message multiple lines long, it also concatenates them on one line. How do I prevent this behaviour? My code used to allow it, but I broke it somehow...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're sending it with an html formatting. Try:

```
$body = nl2br("[From: " . $name . "]\r\n\r\n" . $message);
```

Comment: Doh. I don't even want it HTML, testing line I forgot to remove. Cheers.